# Create Bash loop from JSON string using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am writing a bash script that reads a JSON string then loop based on the JSON values to execute a CLI command.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

jq --version > /dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "jq is required but it's not installed. Aborting."; exit 1; }

read -r -d '' USER_ACTIONS << EOM
{
    "user1": [
        "action1"
    ],
    "user2": [
        "action2",
        "action3"
    ]
    
}
EOM

USERS= #TODO
for user in USERS; do
   ACTIONS= #TODO
   for action in ACTIONS; do
       echo "Executing ${command} ${user}-${action}"
   done   
done
```

If jq is present in the server, how do I populate the USERS and ACTIONS variable?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what command you want to execute, if it can be performed from within jq, it's easier to also move the loop inside. There are several ways to accomplish that. Here are some examples, all yielding the same output:

```bash
jq -r 'to_entries[] | "Executing command \(.key)-\(.value[])"' <<< "$USER_ACTIONS"
```

```bash
jq -r 'keys[] as $user | "Executing command \($user)-\(.[$user][])"' <<< "$USER_ACTIONS"
```

```bash
jq -r --stream '"Executing command \(.[0][0])-\(.[1]? // empty)"' <<< "$USER_ACTIONS"
```

Output:

```
Executing command user1-action1
Executing command user2-action2
Executing command user2-action3
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems better to play with vanilla [js](/questions/tagged/js) (`nodejs`):

```
const myvar={
    "user1": [
        "action1"
    ],
    "user2": [
        "action2",
        "action3"
    ]
};

for (let user in myvar) {
     myvar[user].forEach((action) => {
        console.log("Executing command " + user + "-" + action);
    });
}
```

### Output

```
Executing command user1-action1
Executing command user2-action2
Executing command user2-action3
```

### Usage

```
node script.js
```

### Usage with bash

You can remove **Executing** string, then:

```
node script.js | bash
```

Comment: Hi giles, thanks for the answer. Yes, I considered using nodejs. But couple of reasons: 1) It uses a lot of linux command and existing binaries, I hide those to simplify the questions 2) CMIIW, installing jq is much lighter than installing whole nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a users                        # array of users
declare -A actions                      # array of actions indexed by user

read -r -d '' user_actions << EOM
{
    "user1": [
        "action1"
    ],
    "user2": [
        "action2",
        "action3"
    ]
}
EOM

while IFS=$'\t' read -r key val; do
    users+=( "$key" )                   # add the user to the array "users"
    actions[$key]="$val"                # associate the actions with the user
done < <(jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value[]] | @tsv' <<< "$user_actions")

for user in "${users[@]}"; do           # loop over "users"
    IFS=$'\t' read -r -a vals <<< "${actions[$user]}"
    for action in "${vals[@]}"; do
        echo yourcommand "$user" "$action"
    done
done
```

Output:

```
yourcommand user1 action1
yourcommand user2 action2
yourcommand user2 action3
```

**[Explanations]**

- The `jq` command outputs TSV which looks like:

```
user1\taction1
user2\taction2\taction3
```

where `\t` represents a tab character used as a field delimiter.

- The first `read` builtin command assigns `key` to the first field and `val`
  to the remaining field(s). If `val` contains two or more fields,
  it will be splitted with tne next `read` builtin in the next loop.
- if the output looks good, drop `echo` and replace the string `yourcommand` with the command name.